# html links still boxed after closing the code

Tags: html, css

ive wrote this code , and every link shared after this code is sent, is showing the black background and i cant figure out why, what am i doing wrong im a complete noob with this so any help will be much appreciated.

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}   

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="growbox">
  <span>  
  <font color=red><b>* * * <u>IMAGE HOSTS</u> * * *</b></font>  <font color=blue>(Click to Open/ Click toClose)</font>
  <br>
  <font color=#7ec2cf><b><u>"Test site"</b></u></font>
  <font color=Red><b>They Will Open In a New Tab When Clicked</b></font> <br>
  <font color=red>Test sites (if one does not work try another)</font>
  <br>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a> 
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>
  <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><b>test</b></a>  
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: HERES THE CSS<style>
.growbox {
  display: none;
}
.growbox+span {
  /*style of the "closed" msg, like*/
  max-height: 1.2em;
  /*two lines*/
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.growbox:checked+span {
  /*style of the "opened" msg, like*/
  max-height: 180em;
}
</style>

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It's running fine on my system. if you care to be more specific about the problem then I might be able to help you!

Comment: i use as a script command in a chat board, but everytime i post that, and share any link after that, the link i share, shows a black bos around like the one defined by the style, and the whole chat board needs to be rebooted

Comment: im also getting Selector expected. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector when i inspect it in a html in firefox, like isaid im new to this so sorry in advance i cant give a more detailed response

Comment: do i need to add the <div> / </div> tags in there somewhere

Comment: @gavcollins So you wnat the test buttons to have an initial background-color: black and it should change to red on click or?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from style css

`background-color: black;`

Comment: but removing that loses the effect of it being black in my script, that loses the whole effect im going for , i want the black there , within the script, but dont want it there in any links that are shared after it , and doing that now leaves the links shared after the script red when hovered off, which is again taking up more than a single line, i just want to know whats missing to close the code so the css isnt still implemented after the script is shared,,,,,,,anyone ???